# Real solutions of $x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+x}}}$

Tags: contest-math, real-numbers

Find all real solutions of the equation:

$$x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+x}}}$$

**My approach:**

One idea was square $3$ times untill get a equation and try factoring it. Another was try to get a system, calling, for example, $y=\sqrt{2+x}$, but I didn't have luck with any of them.

Any idea?

Comment: After squaring three times, I guess that you have obtained an $8$th degree equation. Can you write it?

Comment: $x \in [-2, 2]$, actually $x \in [\sqrt 2, 2]$

Comment: @stud_iisc Right

Comment: And $x>\sqrt 2$

Comment: @ajotatxe: I can write it but is very hard to try to factorize it.

Answer (score 0):

after squaring three times and factorizing we get $$- \left( x-2 \right)  \left( x+1 \right)  \left( {x}^{3}-3\,x+1
 \right)  \left( {x}^{3}+{x}^{2}-2\,x-1 \right) 
=0$$ can you go further from here?

Comment: Is $x=2$ a solution?

Comment: Both of those cubics also give you three (*2) more solutions ... but they are quite messy ... cube roots of root threes.

Comment: No, $x \neq 2$, we get $2 = \sqrt 2$ when we insert $x=2$ in the original equation.

Comment: @stud_iisc ... I think you can choose to take the negative root on the second square rooting.

Comment: i have squared the equation, so you must make a control if the solutions fulfill also your equation

Comment: Yes, $x=2$ is a solution if you take $\sqrt4 = -2$

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Yes. Now makes sense. Thanks!